# Firefox - Hide Ellipsis Menu

Tags: firefox

I'd like to hide this menu from ever appearing in firefox's address bar. I have no use for it and it adds visual noise. How can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Add this to your `userChrome.css`:

```
#pageActionButton {
    display: none !important;
}
```

(there is no direct alternative in `about:config`).

#### Detailed

1. Go to `about:support` in the address bar.
2. Click the `Open Directory` button in the `Profile Directory` line.
3. In this directory, create a directory called `chrome`.
4. In the `chrome` directory, create a file called `userChrome.css` (note the capital `C` in `userChrome`).
5. In this file, add these exact lines:

```
#pageActionButton {
    display: none !important;
}
```

6. Restart your browser

#### Bonus

To remove the redundant vertical separator (`|`) that remained where the ellipsis used to be, add this to `userChrome.css`:

```
#pageActionSeparator {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Generally, to edit stuff in that area, you can use [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1189009#answer-1037543) (from Firefox support).